# Rails group method outputting wrong average in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a search query (using Postgres) that uses a few search params and collects the average yield of treatments. The issue I'm having here is that the average of treatments is the same for both results which is wrong. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this query, but it seems to be collecting the average for all and outputting the same result for each treatment:

```
@search = Trial.joins(:region, :property, :quality_datum, treatment_selections: :treatment)
.where("EXTRACT(year from season_year) BETWEEN #{params[:start_year]} AND #{params[:end_year]}")
.where('regions.name': params[:select_region]).where('properties.name': params[:select_property])  
.group('treatments.id')
.select('treatments.name, AVG(quality_data.yield) as yield')
```

Which outputs:

```
|    Name     | Average |
| Treatment 1 |   8.68  |       
| Treatment 2 |   8.68  |
```

Which is wrong, it should be:

```
|    Name     | Average |
| Treatment 1 |   9.27  |       
| Treatment 2 |   7.25  |
```

Quality_data.yield numbers are:

**Treatment 1:** 9.86, 9.79, 8.16 which an average should = 9.27

**Treatment 2:** 10.01, 4.89, 6.85 which an average should = 7.25

The output of the query is:

```
SELECT treatments.name, AVG(quality_data.yield) as yield FROM "trials" 
INNER JOIN "regions" ON "regions"."id" = "trials"."region_id" 
INNER JOIN "properties" ON "properties"."id" = "trials"."property_id" 
INNER JOIN "treatment_selections" ON "treatment_selections"."trial_id" = "trials"."id" 
INNER JOIN "quality_data" ON "quality_data"."treatment_selection_id" = "treatment_selections"."id" 
INNER JOIN "treatment_selections" "treatment_selections_trials" ON "treatment_selections_trials"."trial_id" = "trials"."id" 
INNER JOIN "treatments" ON "treatments"."id" = "treatment_selections_trials"."treatment_id" WHERE (EXTRACT(year from season_year) BETWEEN 2016 AND 2018) AND "regions"."name" = $1 AND "properties"."name" = $2 GROUP BY treatments.id
```

**Associations**

```
class Trial
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :treatment_selections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :quality_datum, through: :treatment_selections
end

class TreatmentSelection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trial
  belongs_to :treatment
  has_many :quality_datum, dependent: :destroy
end

class Treatment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :treatment_selections
end

class Region < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trials
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trials
end
```

Comment: From my understanding, your DB query itself returns incorrect data? You may want to play with database console directly then and check if the range of records taken into account by your query is correct.

Comment: Thanks @Marek. Good suggestion. It’s been doing my head in for a long time now, and I can’t see where it’s going wrong, hopefully your suggestion might show where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several solutions, over several days I had an inkling that the `treatments.id` and `treatment_selections.treatment_id` weren't matching as they should.

I changed the query to the following and it seems to have worked as it should:

```
@search = Trial.joins(:region, :property, :quality_datum, :treatment_selections)
.joins('INNER JOIN treatments ON treatments.id = treatment_selections.treatment_id')
.select('treatments.name, AVG(quality_data.yield) as yield') 
.group('treatments.id')
.where("EXTRACT(year from season_year) BETWEEN #{params[:start_year]} AND #{params[:end_year]}")
.where('regions.name': params[:select_region]).where('properties.name': params[:select_property])
```

The difference here is that I'm forcing the INNER JOIN on the treatment and treatment_selection tables to the corresponding ids.